# 32 GB USB Capacity degrades to 5.5 KB Capacity

Tags: usb-flash-drive, rufus

When I was trying to make bootable USB using Rufus it suddenly got stuck at a point. I was forced to end Rufus. When I look back to the capacity of USB got 5.5 KB. It doesn't get actual capacity even after formatting or doing everything I know.

Any help would be very useful.

[image: here is shot of gparted]

Comment: Did the drive work before you've formatted it with Rufus? Have you actually moved files larger than 1 MB on that drive?

Comment: Yes, it was 5GB of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The USB disk seems to have died. The firmware in particular is loused up
and reporting an incorrect capacity.

There might exist tools for your brand of disk to restore the firmware,
but even if such a tool exists, the chances for success are low.

The best solution would be to replace the disk.

Comment: Exactly this solution would be working because Rufus removed whole firmware and replaced with something else. I having simmtronics SB01232, did they have recovery tool?

Comment: Rufus does not operate on the disk's firmware. All it does is make the disk work hard. If the disk was close to failing, this hard work would cause to finally fail.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have linux so why were you using windows tool rufus to make bootable usb??

start with output from `fdisk -l` and `ls -l /dev/disk-by-uuid` but I would probably go to a lower-level tool like `cfdisk /dev/sdc` and see what that shows up. From there you can delete all and create partitions you want (or leave blank)

And if you have a bootable image, copy it to the device from linux with `dd`

Comment: I have did it in another windows PC, i will try your given steps.

Comment: _"You appear to have linux so why were you using windows tool rufus to make bootable usb??"_ - people are free to use whatever OS they want, including multiple ones.

Comment: `cfdisk /dev/sdc` says Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Also `dd` says `dd: error writing '/dev/sdc': No space left on device`

Comment: It looks whole partition table destroyed. Is there is no way to again get it back with Rufus?

Comment: @gronostaj . yes. And people are free to call a plumber to fix their wiring. Doesn't mean it's the best thing to achieve the outcome they want.

Comment: @ardarsh raj, I have no idea if you can get it back with rufus. Just checked and gparted does have the option to write partition tables (mbr or gpt) from the Device menu. This will nominally "blank" the device (though not overwrite any data). Once you do that you will be able to create partitions as normal.

Comment: I don't know about Rufus either but probably not. Now, you're showing GParted so just do  Device > Create new partition table. if it doesn't work your last chance is to use MKUSB and its specific feature "restore to a standard storage device". Then if at all convenient you can use the same tool to burn the ISO. I Windows you may try the much easier Balena Etcher. Using Rufus in Linux I have to agree is ridiculous.